# Filtered results are not precise

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a job board app using AngularJS to learn about the framework. I got the app to pull data from JSON and added a few filters. While the filters work alright, they don't always display the right results for the search query. Here's the code:

```
  <h1 class="text-center">Active Jobs</h1>
  <div class = "row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "search" placeholder="Search Jobs"></div>
  <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
    <label>Sort by:
            <select ng-model="jobSearch">
                <option value="location" selected>Location</option>
                <option value="salary">Salary</option>
                <option value="role">Role</option>                
            </select>
        </label>
    <label class="formgroup">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="order" name ="order" checked> ascending  
    </label>
    <label class="formgroup">   
      <input type="radio" ng-model="order" name ="order" value = "reverse"> descending
    </label>    
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:search | orderBy: jobSearch:order">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2><a href = "#/jobs/{{ jobs.indexOf(job) }}">{{ job.designation }}</a></h2>
      <p>{{ job.location }}</p>
      <p>{{ job.role }}</p>
      <p>{{ job.salary  | currency }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created jobs in locations like Austin, San Francisco, Hertfordshire etc. When I start typing, say, "He" or "Her", in addition to the Hertfordshire listing, few other listings show up as well. On closer examination, I found that words with these letters appear in the description of those listings. The same happens when I search using role (remote, full time, part time) as well. How do I ensure that queries are performed only on the attribute selected in the drop down and not the entire listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search in

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:search | orderBy: jobSearch:order">
```

is bound to a string in your input. When using a String in a filter, all objects in array with string properties containing the search value will be returned.

If you want to search only on location, change the ng-model of your input to :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "search.location" placeholder="Search Jobs">
```

**Edit**

It should be easier to use a function in your controller

```
$scope.search(value) {
     return value[$scope.jobSearch] == $scope.searchTerm;
}
```

In your html, you bind the input search to the searchTerm :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "searchTerm" placeholder="Search Jobs">
```

And your filter to the search function :

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:search() | orderBy: jobSearch:order">
```

Hope that help

Comment: I'm using a drop down and I would like to use other options in the menu (salary, role) to be used as well. Is there a way to adapt this solution in that case?

Comment: You might try ng-model="search[jobSearch]" instead of ng-model="search.location". Though you will have to empty the search object on jobSearch change.

Comment: I edit my answer with a solution that use a function which should fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:{jobSearch: search} | orderBy: jobSearch:order">
```

check this one

Comment: This return no values since this return jobs where `job['jobSearch'] == search`, not `job[jobSearch] == search`.